# Initialize vectors in classes

Tags: c++

Is it possible to initialize a vector in a sruct or class. here is an example how i want to make it work

```
class MenuItem {
    std::string name;         // Name of menu item
    void        (*func)();    // Function of menu item
    MenuPage*   subPage;      // Pointer to submenu
};

class MenuPage {
    std::string menuTitle;
    std::vector<MenuItem> menuItems;
};

static const MenuPage menuMain = {
    "Main menu",
    {{ "Item1", 0, 0 },
     { "Item2", 0, 0 },
     { "Item3", 0, 0 }}
};
```

this structure should represent a dynamic console menu in windows.
I use a singleton pattern to access the menu. A membervar of type MenuPage* is saved as the menu entry point in the object.

so if it isn't possible, what alternative methods could you advise?

Comment: You meant `struct` instead of `class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make those members as `public` and it will be initialized in C++11. Otherwise you can use initializer list and constructor:

```
class MenuPage {
    std::string menuTitle;
    std::vector<MenuItem> menuItems;
public:
    MenuPage (std::string s, std::vector<MenuItem> m) :
    menuTitle(s), menuItems(m) {}
};

static const MenuPage menuMain (
    "Main menu",
    {{ "Item1", 0, 0 },
     { "Item2", 0, 0 },
     { "Item3", 0, 0 }}
);
```

Note that, you should do same thing fot `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, you can do exactly that (or at least, you could if the class members were public).

If you're stuck in the past, then it's messier; either write a function to create and return the vector, or use something like the [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library.